# How to push an object to another in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what i use to assign one object into another

```
var check = Object.assign(product, cart_item);
```

But it does not added as key in object i.e (var check)

See the image below [image]

Please share your thoughts on this, how do I add it as another key like the `0,1,2` keys in image.

code :-

```
var product = {
        brand: data.product.brandName,
        category: category,
        country: 'IN',
        email: Cookies.get('useremail'),
        imageUrl: data.product.media.thumbnails["0"].src,
        location: 'product page',
        magento_product_id: data.product.productKey,
        manufacturer: 'Widow',
        microcategory: 'Printed Leggings',
        name: data.product.name,
        price: data.product.price.price.value,
        product_id: data.product.productKey,
        products:cart_item,
        quantity: 1,
        regular_price: data.product.price.price.value,
        size: '',
        size_type: data.selectedVariant.label,
        special_category: 'Brands,Char Test Category,Widow,Widow',
        special_price: data.product.price.specialPrice,
        stock_quantity: data.selectedVariant.totalQuantity,
        swatch: data.selectedVariant.color,
        trend: 'WID Darkest Hour 2020',
        type: data.product.type,
        url: data.product.url
    };
    

    data.session.cart.items.forEach(function (properties) {
        var items = {};
        items["brand"] = properties.product.display_brand;
        items["category"] = "";
        items["country"]= "IN";
        items["imageUrl"]=properties.product.image.url;
        items["magento_product_id"]=properties.product.id;
        items["manufacturer"]="";
        items["microcategory"]="";
        items["name"]=properties.product.name;
        items["price"]=properties.product.price_range.minimum_price.final_price.value;
        items["product_id"]=properties.id;
        items["quantity"]=properties.quantity;
        items["regular_price"]=properties.product.price_range.minimum_price.regular_price.value;
        items["size"]=properties.product.size;
        items["size_type"]=properties.product.size_label;
        items["special_category"]="";
        items["special_price"]=properties.product.special_price;
        items["stock_quantity"]="";
        items["swatch"]=properties.product.color_label;
        items["trend"]="";
        items["type"]=properties.product.__typename;
        items["url"]=properties.url;
        cart_item.push(items)
    });
        var check = Object.assign(product, cart_item);
        console.log(check);
```

Expected output:
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Your expected output is unclear.

Comment: i have added expected output

Comment: @devphp I have a feeling that this issue has something to do with PHPs associative arrays, and that you confuse JS Objects with associative arrays. But there is a major difference: **JS arrays are always numeric**. What you would probably call an associative array, is in JS **not an array** at all.

Comment: Thankyou thomas but is their any way i add merge those two objects ?

Answer (score 1):

The point of `Object.assign` is to merge the properties of objects.

```js
const first = { first: 1, first_2: 2 };
const second = { second: 3, second_2: 4 };
const result = Object.assign(first, second);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to add a new property to an object, then you need to do so explicitly:

```js
const first = { first: 1, first_2: 2 };
const second = { second: 3, second_2: 4 };
const result = { "0": first };
result["1"] = second;
console.log(result);
```

… but if you want a sequential list of numbered objects, then you should be organising them in an **array** and not building your own object in the first place.

```js
const first = { first: 1, first_2: 2 };
const second = { second: 3, second_2: 4 };
const result = [ first ];
result.push(second);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Actually if you `assign()` an array into an object it will create the sequential  keys since the `Object.keys()` of an array are the integer indexes, so you don't need to do so explicitly.

Comment: @pilchard — No, it won't. It will create (on the array) the *named* keys from the object you are assigning.

Comment: I am not getting the exact answer,

Comment: ok @Quentin you have written great examples. I am checking if i can modify and make it work. Can you please give it a try to add answer with variables that i used(code specific answer) ?

Comment: @Amaarrockz — Please don't answer in the comments of other answers. `var check = [...cart_items, ...[product]]; ` is also completely broken. It will overwrite the existing `0` property with a new `0` property instead of finding the next number in the sequence to assign.

Comment: @devphp — Create a `products` variable that is an array. Put the value that is your current `product` variable inside that array. Call `push` on that array to add items to it.

Comment: Can you please add it as answer @Quentin ?

Answer (score -1):

You are merging an array with an object in your `Object.assign()` call which will create a key: value pair for each element in the array using the integer index as the key and the element at that index for the value.

```js
const product = { first: 1, second: 2 };
const cart_item = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const check = Object.assign(product, cart_item);

console.log(check);
```

Or, in the case of Quentin's example...

```js
const objects = [{ first: 1, first_2: 2 }, { second: 3, second_2: 4 }];
const result = Object.assign({}, objects);

console.log(result);
// { '0': { first: 1, first_2: 2 }, '1': { second: 3, second_2: 4 } }

console.log(objects)
// [ { first: 1, first_2: 2 }, { second: 3, second_2: 4 } ]
// (the array is unaltered)
```

Comment: i cannot add key like "first" & "Second" i need to add the last key dynamically to cart_items

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted, this is an illustration of what the OP is doing with their `Object.assign(product, cart_item);` call, where `product` is an object and `cart_item` is an array.

Comment: shall i convert to array & do the merge ?

Comment: I still don't understand your expected output.